Highlight three specific bars in a barplot with ggplot
I am trying to highlight specifc bars in a barplot using ggplot. My end goal would be to have the three bars highlighted in different colors, for example blue, red, orange and I would like to keep the remaining bars lightgreen.
As of now this is my code:
`
#Barplot
Population <-ggplot(data= na.omit(RV), aes(x= reorder(Genotype, Rate), y= Rate)) +

  geom_col(aes(fill = Genotype != "RAPxSPL 410-1")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "lightgreen" ), guide = "none") +
    labs(title = "RAPxSPL 410-1 x Line V - Ratio VIP/MOCK", x = "Genotype", y = "Ratio VIP/MOCK")

Population + coord_flip()`

I have understood that I have to create new levels of fill= but each time I try I do get all bars in grey


Make a new column with 4 unique values, one for each highlight and one for the other bars, then add something like scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "orange", "lightgreen")). I would show you, but your example is not reproducible. Alternatively, have a look at the {gghighlight} package.

Do you mean something like:  samples <- data.frame(controls = c("RAPxSPL 410-1","BER 489-1", "RH"))

More something like RV$my_fill <- with(RV, dplyr::case_when(Genotype == "RAPxSPL 410-1" ~ "a", Genotype == "BER 489-1" ~ "b", Genotype == "RH" ~ "c", TRUE ~ "d")). Then use aes(fill = my_fill) in geom_col.

The trick is to create a named vector of fill colors, with one vector element per genotype. This is done with setNames. In preparation for it, first match the genotypes column with the genotypes to highlight. Then get rid of the NA's, substituting index 1 to the light green color for those NA's. This has created an index into the fill colors vector. Then set the names, duplicating the fill colors with the index i.
The test data set is an example data set with the relevant columns only.
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2024)
RV <- data.frame(
  Genotype = LETTERS[1:20],
  Rate = runif(20)
)
# the bars to highlight
hi <- sample(RV$Genotype, 3L)

i <- match(RV$Genotype, hi) + 1L
i[is.na(i)] <- 1L
fill <- c("lightgreen", "blue", "red", "orange")
fill <- setNames(fill[i], RV$genotype)

ggplot(RV, aes(reorder(Genotype, Rate), Rate, fill = Genotype)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill) +
  labs(title = "RAPxSPL 410-1 x Line V - Ratio VIP/MOCK", x = "Genotype", y = "Ratio VIP/MOCK") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()


Created on 2024-09-24 with reprex v2.1.0
